# Strange Error in VB.net web browser

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a app on vb.net in which I am using a web brower. The code is working fine, but I some popup is coming every time I open the app.

This is the popup:

[image]

How can I remove this Script Error. Below is my code:

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form4


    Private Sub btnMapIt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMapIt.Click

        Try
            Dim street As String = String.Empty
            Dim city As String = String.Empty
            Dim state As String = String.Empty
            Dim zip As String = String.Empty

            Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder()
            queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")
            queryAddress.Append(TextBox1.Text)

            webBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString())

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Unable to Retrieve Map")

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
        Try
            TextBox1.Text = Form10.TextBox6.Text
            'txtStreet.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Welcome to Google Maps", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in  a FormLoad event, have a look at [this property in doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Thanks !! I didn't know that there was something like this.